# Adding vertical line in each time series subplot in multiple time series

Tags: python, timeserieschart

I have multiple time series. Each with common time stamp. I have plotting subplot for each time series. Now I want to add vertical line in each subplot. I have tried for loop. But it does not work.

```
url_jobs="https://assets.datacamp.com/production/repositories/1259/datasets/1c6b4a977a3c14f2a00c2d74694b208d9ac86443/ch5_employment.csv"
jobs=pd.read_csv(url_jobs)
jobs['datestamp']=pd.to_datetime(jobs['datestamp'])
jobs=jobs.set_index('datestamp')
plot2=jobs.plot(subplots=True,layout=(4,4),figsize=(20,16),sharex=True,sharey=False)
for each in plot2:
    each.axvline('2008-09-01',color='red',linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a 4 x 4 layout `DataFrame.plot` will return a 4 x 4 numpy array. You can call `flatten` on it in order to turn it into a 1D array:

```
url_jobs="https://assets.datacamp.com/production/repositories/1259/datasets/1c6b4a977a3c14f2a00c2d74694b208d9ac86443/ch5_employment.csv"
jobs=pd.read_csv(url_jobs)
jobs['datestamp']=pd.to_datetime(jobs['datestamp'])
jobs=jobs.set_index('datestamp')
plot2=jobs.plot(subplots=True,layout=(4,4),figsize=(20,16),sharex=True,sharey=False)
for each in plot2.flatten():
    each.axvline('2008-09-01',color='red',linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

[image]